# Geth+Teku Nodes Randomly Stop Communicating

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, staking, teku

newbie staker here.

I’ve been trying to set up my Geth/Teku nodes for the past week, but I keep running into a persistent issue –

After starting both nodes, everything runs well for between 5-30 minutes, then they go out of sync, each saying they have not received updates from the other. I’ve tried all of the common trouble shooting stuff I could find to no avail, so I’m at a bit of an impasse. It would be simpler if they never worked, but they both start up and confirm they are receiving updates from the other, before randomly losing connection. Also, they never lose connection to external peers, only to each other.

When the nodes stop syncing they each say -

Geth: “Beacon client online, but no consensus updates received in a while. Please fix your beacon client to follow the chain!”

Teku: “WARN  - Execution Client request timed out. Make sure the Execution Client is online and can respond to requests.”

See relevant hardware+node info below, and please let me know if there’s anything else you need to know that could help identify the issue.

Any help would be really appreciated! I’m pretty lost. Thanks!

**Relevant info -**

Hardware – Running an I9 13900K, Zotac Geforce RTX 4080, with 32 GB of Gskill DDR5 Ram. My Teku node is being stored on my computer’s internal 2TB Western Digital nvme, and my Geth node uses an external Sabrent harddrive bay with 24TBs of 8TB Kingston SSD drives (perhaps the different storage locations could have something to do with it?). All of this is running on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

*Note – I’ve tested my RAM, and it appears to have no issues*

**Geth Node** -  I’m not using a service command (dumb IK), but the flags are -

sudo geth --syncmode full --gcmode archive --cache 8192 --authrpc.jwtsecret /var/lib/jwtsecret/jwt.hex --authrpc.addr localhost --authrpc.port 8551 --datadir /blockchain/ethereum/execution --http --metrics --metrics.influxdb --metrics.influxdb.endpoint http://0.0.0.0:8086 --metrics.influxdb.username geth --metrics.influxdb.password **********

**Teku Node** -

[Unit]
Description=Teku Consensus Layer Client service for Mainnet
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
Documentation=https://www.coincashew.com

[Service]
Type=simple
User=consensus
Group=consensus
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
KillSignal=SIGINT
TimeoutStopSec=900
Environment=JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx5g
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/teku/bin/teku 
--network mainnet 
--data-path /var/lib/teku/ 
--data-storage-mode="prune" 
--initial-state="https://beaconstate.info/eth/v2/debug/beacon/states/finalized" 
--ee-endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8551 
--ee-jwt-secret-file /var/lib/jwtsecret/jwt.hex 
--rest-api-enabled true 
--metrics-enabled true 
--metrics-port 8008 \

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target